# UWP x:Bind with time

Tags: c#, windows, binding, windows-10, uwp

I convert my application from WP 8.1 / W 8.1 to UWP. It includes a timer updating the value of a textbox. Here is the XAML :

```
Text="{Binding CurrentLocalDateTime, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource DateTimeConverter}}"
```

And the data context :

```
    private DateTime currentLocalDateTime;

    public DateTime CurrentLocalDateTime { get { return currentLocalDateTime; } set { currentLocalDateTime = value; OnPropertyChanged("CurrentLocalDateTime"); } }

    private void TimerExecution(object sender, object e)
    {
        CurrentLocalDateTime = DateTime.Now;
    }
```

I'd like to use the new x:Bind bining way, but the control is never updated, with this code :

```
Text="{x:Bind CurrentLocalDateTime, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource DateTimeConverter}}"
```

Data context :

```
    public DateTime CurrentLocalDateTime { get; set; }

    private void TimerExecution(object sender, object e)
    {
        CurrentLocalDateTime = DateTime.Now;
    }
```

What's wrong ?

Thank you very much for your help.
Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you set `CurrentLocalDateTime`, there's nothing to notify your UI that it happened. It works in the first case because you're implementing INotifyPropertyChanged and calling OnPropertyChanged with property name.

```
public DateTime CurrentLocalDateTime 
{ 
    get { return currentLocalDateTime; }  
    set 
    { 
        currentLocalDateTime = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("CurrentLocalDateTime"); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Works fine, thank you. I thought OnPropertyChanged was not necessary for x:Bind, and forgot to test it ;-).

Comment: @RomEh mark as answer if it answered your question ;)